# Convert month, week, day into unix timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, unix-timestamp

In MSSQL how would i take the following pieces of information and convert it to a unix time stamp?

- Month = 3
- Week_In_Month = 2
- Day_of_Week = 1 (first day of the week is
  Sunday)
- seconds_elapsed_during_day = 7200

This would be based on the current year (or any given year). I'v efound various sql queries to convert an actual year/month/day from integer components to unix timestamp but nothing like what I have here.

Just as background, this is going to be used in a database that contains time zone information stored with the above columns indicating the start and stop of DST. I need to be able to tell my developers how to take these values and convert them into a timestamp that can be used in other queries.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: DST start/stop times could be different in different years, you database schema is wrong and you cannot convert your data into timestamp

Comment: unfortunately, this is not "my" schema but one provided by a vendor and at the moment is what I must use. I assume they have a process to update this table as changes are made. If we assume that they (or I) will upkeep this table is there a solution?

Comment: you cannot use incomplete data, instead use more-or-less complete source, like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert 2:00 am on the second Sunday in March to a Unix timestamp, you need to find the second Sunday in the month.  Here is one way:

```
with y as (
      select '2018' as yyyy
    )
select dateadd(day,
               15 - (case when datepart(weekday, yyyy+'-03-01') = 1 then 8
                          else datepart(weekday, yyyy+'-03-01')
                     end),
               yyyy+'-03-01')
from y;
```

Then, you need to subtract 1970-01-01 from this value to get the difference in seconds and add back the 7200:

```
with y as (
      select '2018' as yyyy
    )
select datediff(second, '1970-01-01',
                dateadd(day,
                        15 - (case when datepart(weekday, yyyy+'-03-01') = 1 then 8
                                   else datepart(weekday, yyyy+'-03-01')
                               end),
                         yyyy+'-03-01'
                        )
                 ) + 7200
from y;
```